# Change id values of all rows in table STARTING from a specific number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 1000 rows in a table..

I'm getting the last and next available id (to start from)

```
$latest_id = ("SELECT * FROM `vehicles` WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `vehicles`)");
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when clicking on a button, to change the id value of all 1000 rows + to start from the `$latest_id`

So NOW is:

```
id 1 = car 1
id 2 = car 2
id 3 = car 3
...
```

AFTER

```
id 1001 = car 1
id 1002 = car 2
id 1003 = car 3
...
```

Can someone help me with the sql query please.

Comment: So you want to append `100` to the id's, is that what you're asking?

Comment: nope, 1000 rows is just an example, it can be any number, and that "any" number must be the number which will be the start of the new increment..

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the question. What you posted was unclear for me. You've 2 answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `UPDATE` statement with a `JOIN`

```
UPDATE vehicles as v
JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid
      FROM vehicles) AS x
SET v.id = v.id + x.maxid
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write an `update` statement that cross joins the table with a subquery that computes the maximum value, and then add the maximum value to each `id`:

```
update vehicles v
inner join (select max(id) id from vehicles) vmax
set v.id = vmax.id + v.id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a41fa016549fcb6e79ac08266e7284c6)**

Initial content of the table:

```
id | car  
-: | :----
 1 | car 1
 2 | car 2
 3 | car 3
 4 | car 4
```

After running the query:

```
id | car  
-: | :----
 5 | car 1
 6 | car 2
 7 | car 3
 8 | car 4
```

Comment: OP states: *"AFTER

id 1001 = car 1
id 1002 = car 2
id 1003 = car 3"*. You have *"After running the query:

id | car  
-: | :----
 5 | car 1
 6 | car 2
 7 | car 3
 8 | car 4"*. Unless I didn't grasp what they're asking.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: they want to add the maximum value of `id` to each `id`. They have 1000 records in the table, while in my example there are 4, so `4` is added to each record, not `1000`.

Comment: Scratch that ^ I misunderstood their post. It was unclear for me, the way they posted the `100`s followed by id numbers.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: no pb!

Comment: :) Oh, theoretically, yours was 15 seconds faster :D

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner: it was (and it has a fiddle). But you know what they say about higher rep usually getting the accept in this situation...

Comment: Yeah, I guess.... oh well no biggie huh? :) It'll serve others well also. Both were good answers. *Cheers*